# Google Tango - Load 3D Reconstruction and Localize

Tags: google-project-tango

Hi I'm new to Google Tango and stackoverflow and I'm doing a group project for school using the Tango device. I've searched the site and the web in general, but can't seem to find anything quite like what I'm looking for.

We've successfully used the AreaLearning feature to re-localize within a space and have used the Constructor to create a 3d model of a space. We want to load that model and localize within it so that we can use raycasting to measure the distance to walls.

Is there a way to do this or a better idea of how to obtain the wall (and other obstructions) distances?

thanks, 
Ryan